# Verify that a method call is initiated from a specific Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, truffle-contract, solidity-0.8.x

As my smart contract is >24k, I read that I need to break it into multiple (smaller) smart contracts.

So, my current design is to have a `Core` contract that has all the data in arrays. This `Core` has CRUD (create, read, update, delete) functions.

Then I have another `Create` contract that has the detailed logic on verification, massaging, etc.

Users will execute a method on this `Create` contract (eg `GenerateNewRecord()` ) which processes/validates the inputs, then execute the `Core.Add(newRecord)`.

In this case, inside the `Core.Add()` method, it needs to ensure that it is executed by the `Create` contract, and only the `Create` contract.

How can I do this check?  noting that end-user initiated the `Create.GenerateNewRecord()` which the `Create` contract will call the `Core.Add()` method.

Any advice will be appreciated. Or am I doing this incorrectly?  What is the best-practice way to break large contracts into smaller ones?

In my case, I have a central store, and many functions that need access to this core storage. I am unable to break the storage into different smart contracts.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use something like OpenZeppelin's `AccessControl`, create a role for the `Create` contract and grant that role as part of the deployment.

Comment: Would openzeppelin AccessControl be tracking the USER's address which called the Create.GenerateNewRecord() instead of the Create contract's address?

Comment: The [`AccessControl` api](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access#AccessControl) only provides the base functionality. It is up to you how it is used, for example you could `require()` the caller to have certain role, ensuring only an approved contract could interact with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way of doing it would be to create an address variable inside the Create contract, store the address of the Core contract in constructor and inside the Add function, add a check like `require(createAddress == msg.sender).`

But the best way of doing it would be using AccessControl contract from openzepplin as mentioned by Ismael. AccessControl allows you to add multiple roles, you can add a role for CreateContract and use it with modifier onlyRole.

You can read more about AccessControl on [Openzepplin AccessControl Page](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control)

Comment: Update: I confirm that when User calls ContractA, which then calls ContractB; then in this case, _msgSender() in ContractB returns ContractA, and not User who initiated the call). Thanks.

Comment: @JosephLee this is the expected behavior. If you need user's address. You can pass it as a function parameter to the second contract.